# Proving $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = 0$ implies $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)g(x) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $x_{\star} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ Also, suppose $g : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded; that is, there is a real number $c$ so that $|g(x)| \leq c$ for all $x \in A$. Prove $\lim_{x\to x_{\star}} f(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to x_{\star}} [g(x)f(x)] = 0$.

---

Here's my try:

Since $|g(x)| \leq c$ for all $x$, we have $|g(x)f(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to x_{\star}} g(x)f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to x_{0}} c\cdot f(x) = 0$, so we are done.

For some reason, I think this is wrong. I think the formal way to do it is to introduce a sequence with limit point $x_{\star}$, but I have no clue how to do it this way. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your argument is fine except that you forgot absolute value signs in the second line.

Comment: so why does it matter that $x_{\star}$ is a limit point?

Comment: is there a way to do it with a sequence ?

Comment: There is no assumption on continuity, so I don't see anyway to pass anything through by sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but your argument is *technically* incorrect. You write at one point $\lim_{x\to x_\star}g(x)f(x)\le \lim_{x\to x_{\star}}c\cdot f(x)$, but we have not yet justified that the limit $\lim_{x\to x_\star}g(x)f(x)$ exists, so it is not correct to put it in an inequality.

A formal way to prove it is to note, as you did, that $|g(x)|\le c$ for all $x\in A$, and let $\epsilon > 0$ be a challenge number. Then since $f(x)\to 0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon/c$ whenever $|x-x_\star| < \delta$ for $x\in A$. If $|x-x_\star|<\delta$, then we have
$$
|g(x)f(x)| = |g(x)|\cdot|f(x)| \le c\cdot |f(x)| < \epsilon.
$$
As $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, $\lim_{x\to x_\star}g(x)f(x)$ exists and is equal to $0$.

---

**Remark.** There are equivalent ways to prove a limit is equal to something over $\mathbb R^n$, one using sequences, and one using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. The formulation of this using the sequence approach would proceed in much the same way:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be a challenge number. We will show that for any sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x_\star$, then $g(x_n)f(x_n)\to 0$. Since $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to x_\star$, there is some integer $N$ so that for all integers $n \ge N$, we have $|f(x_n)| \le \epsilon/c$. If $n \ge N \dots$,

I will let you finish the proof.

Comment: so is $x$ a sequence ?

Comment: @stackofhay42: No, $x$ isn't a sequence. See my edit; there are two ways to phrase limits in $\Bbb R^n$. I outlined the one using sequences for you---it is very similar in flavor to the one using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: Ok, you write "Then since $f(x) \rightarrow f(x_{\star})$". in the second paragraph. Do you mean to write $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: @stackofhay42: Yes, good catch.